# why is my JavaScript code not behaving as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

Couple of queries relating to some JavaScript I have written that is not performing how I think it ought to. it is a password validation form with 2 input fields that allow the user to write a password and then re enter it to see if there are matches or not

here is the function.

```
function passwordValidation(){


    var uname = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("cPassword").value;
    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";
    var passReq = new RegExp ("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\"\.\[\]_£|`¬':;~{}<>()#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,20}$");



    if (uname.length < 1 || pword.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }

    if(passReq.test(pword1)){
        DIMR = "Does Meet Requirements";
    }else {
        DIMR = "Does Not Meet Requirements";
    }

    if (uname == pword){
        match = "Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
    } else{
        match = "No Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
    }
    document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
    document.getElementById("reqMeeting").innerHTML = DIMR;
}
```

Firstly, why is it ignoring the first if statement? when I load up the code in the browser and run it. As soon as I type values into the first input box, the second one turns red. even though the if statement clearly says do not do this if input a OR input b is blank.

Secondly, the `.test`  part is not working correctly. Perhaps my code is wrong but to me that is saying if the regular expression `passReq` matches the `pword1` value then either print out `"does/does not meet requirements"`. I have also changed this to the variable name `passReq.test(uname)` and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because that is a separate `if` condition. So, it will move on to the next condition regardless of the outcome. I suppose you will have to use `else` part with the first `if` condition to get the expected result that you're wanting.

```
function passwordValidation() {
    var uname = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("cPassword").value;
    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";
    var passReq = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\"\.\[\]_£|`¬':;~{}<>()#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,20}$");
    if (uname.length < 1 || pword.length < 1) {
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    } else {  // this should solve the problem
        if (passReq.test(pword)) {
            DIMR = "Does Meet Requirements";
        } else {
            DIMR = "Does Not Meet Requirements";
        }
        if (uname == pword) {
            match = "Match!";
            cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
        } else {
            match = "No Match!";
            cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
        }
        document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
        document.getElementById("reqMeeting").innerHTML = DIMR;
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach increases the cyclomatic complexity. But anyway the outcome is correct //check

Comment: Fantastic. how simple! thanks dude. any ideas on the second part regarding why my "Does/does not meet requirements" message wont show? i want it to appear in the same way the "match/no match" appears. no worries if not

Comment: @BlueShark probably it could be that reqMeeting is not visible?

Comment: @AmitJoki i took it out by accident. but now at the top of my html it looks like this: '<p id="combination"></p> <p id="reqMeeting"></p>' and even when i type in something that is reg ex valid I still get the message "does not meet requirements" rather than "does meet requirements"

Comment: @BlueShark can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @AmitJoki and according to regexpal.com this expression should validate 'AAbb123.'

Comment: @AmitJoki no luck then?

Comment: @BlueShark sorry didn't notice your comment. Looking into it

Comment: @AmitJoki no worries found an answer already. thanks for your help tho